# setting variable to output of c program with command line arguments in python

Tags: python, c, subprocess, command-line-arguments

I am trying to use a python script in which a variable is set to the output of a c program test.c which requires command line arguments.  Below is my c program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
       int lat;
       lat=atoi(argv[1]);
       printf("-->%d\n",lat);
}
```

The python program is:

```
  import subprocess

  for lat in range(80,-79,-1):
           cmd = '"./a.out" {}'.format(lat)
           print "cmd is ",cmd
           parm31=subprocess.call(cmd,shell=True)
           print "parm is ",parm31
```

I have compiled test.c to get a.out.  My goal is to have an output when running the python program with the c program (test.c or a.out) embedded in it is to have an output of:

```
 parm is -->80
 parm is -->79
 parm is -->78
 ...
 parm is -->-77
 parm is -->-78
```

I am unfortunately not getting to output but other values for the number component of the variable and some other undesired output.  How do I tweak this program in order to get the correct output?

Comment: You should also post the actual output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [[Python 2.Docs]: subprocess.**call**(*args, *, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, shell=False*)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) (**emphasis** is mine):

> Run the command described by *args*. Wait for command to complete, **then return the `returncode` attribute**.

To make things work:

- Use *check_output* instead
- Make the command to be carried a list (not string)
- Don't pass `shell=True`

```py
import subprocess

for lat in range(80, -79, -1):
    cmd = ["\"./a.out\"", "{}".format(lat)]
    print "Command is ", " ".join(cmd)
    out = subprocess.check_output(cmd)
    print "Command output is ", out.strip()
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested and I now get this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cleanita.py", line 6, in <module>
    parm31=subprocess.check_output(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 568, in check_output

Comment: and also: process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory  How do I resolve this issue???

Comment: I added a small correction to the code. Based on your error, it's not my copy / pasted code you're executing. Please add the value you assign to *cmd* if the error persists. Let me know how it works out.